# Editing `My Account` sidebar in magento 2

Tags: magento2, layout, sidebar

*How can I edit sidebar and delete few nav links*

I turned on the debugger hint, which shows me the various path, but I am not able to figure out how can I edit those nav links

[image]

Closest I came to `collapsible.phtml`

```
<div class="block <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getBlockCss() ?>">
<div class="title <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getBlockCss() ?>-title" data-mage-init='{"toggleAdvanced": {"toggleContainers": "#<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getBlockCss() ?>", "selectorsToggleClass": "active"}}'>
    <strong><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getBlockTitle() ?></strong>
</div>
<div class="content <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getBlockCss() ?>-content" id="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getBlockCss() ?>">
    <?= $block->getChildHtml() ?>
</div>
```

On further digging, `$block->getChildHtml()` gets all the side bar nav links, 
so if i write something link this,  `$block->getChildHtml(`name`)`
so i explored layout xml files, but i am not able to figured which xml file it is and how to find `name` attribute in that xml file for which i can call `$block->getChildHtml(`name`)`

Comment: @Mohit Kumar Arora
Sir, I am using Magento 2.3.0 and I want to add some custom link and want to remove as well but I am unable to do that. Would you please help me??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to remove some links from the customer account sidebar, you can do by following steps:

1. Go to your Magento installation folder.
2. Then open **`vendor/magento/module-customer/view/frontend/layout`** folder.
3. Copy the **`customer_account.xml`** file to the **`app/design/frontend/{ThemePackage}/{theme}/Magento_Customer/layout`** folder. Open the copied file to edit.
4. You should add the next code before the **`</body>`** tag. We will remove the My Wish List link, as an example.

```
<referenceBlock name="customer-account-navigation-wish-list-link" remove="true"/>
```

Similarly, you can remove other links as well.

Please let me know if you have any questions.